# What does export variable without an equals sign do?

Tags: bash

There's a bash script on my linux machine with these two lines:

```
[ -r /etc/java/java.conf ] && . /etc/java/java.conf
export JAVA_HOME
```

What does the export JAVA_HOME do? Usually I thought export VARIABLE_NAME=something sets the variable to something.

What does running export JAVA_HOME without setting it to something do?

I tried running it on the commandline, but nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)?

Comment: To be fair the documentation that you linked doesn't really address what the OP has asked - @melpomene

Comment: @JonnyHenly "*Mark each name to be passed to child processes in the environment.*" - That's what `export` does.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but possibly still helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export

Comment: @melpomene right - but you can see where someone might be confused by `export VAR_NAME` when they're used to seeing `export VAR_NAME=foo` or `VAR_NAME=foo; export VAR_NAME`.

Comment: Here's a question: Do you know what `foo=bar` does, and how that differs from `export foo=bar`? If you think that all variable assignments in shell require `export`, then that requires more background to answer.

Comment: ...btw, re: `export VARIABLE_NAME=something` -- all-caps names are reserved for variables that impact how tools defined by the shell or OS work; you don't want to use them for your own names. See fourth paragraph of the relevant POSIX definition at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html -- granted, that document is only explicitly applicable to environment variables, and not all shell variables *are* environment variables, but they do share a namespace so the conventions apply.

Comment: [Aside: Did you know that if a variable is already exported, then all changes go straight to the environment, so you don't need to export it again? So in many contexts `export PATH=$PATH:foo` is silly, because `PATH` is already an environment variable, so `PATH=$PATH:foo` would do the exact same thing].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two lines of code (better to use double brackets):

```
[[ -r /etc/java/java.conf ]] && . /etc/java/java.conf
export JAVA_HOME
```

...equates to this:

`-r` checks if `/etc/java/java.conf` exists and read permission is granted.

`&&` if the condition above is true then source the file.

`export JAVA_HOME` takes the previously-assigned value of `$JAVA_HOME` from the sourced file making it available to subprocesses rather than only within the shell.

- [What does "export" do in shell programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411455/what-does-export-do-in-shell-programming)
- [What does "source" do?](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do)
- [Conditional statements in bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html#sect_07_01_01)

Comment: It doesn't "take it from the read file" in the `export` command -- that was done earlier, when it was sourced, which assigned a shell variable. This exports the shell variable, making it an environment variable also. These are very distinct operations; an explanation that conflates them doesn't help understanding.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thank you!

Comment: NP -- as edited, I think this is a very clear and helpful answer!