# Set variable inside a shell script to be used outside for the next command

Tags: shell

I am trying to use a Shell Variable inside a shell script , My shell script is as below

`HerculesResponse=$(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{ "testID": "591dc3cc4d5c8100054cc30b", "testName": "stagetest", "poolID": "5818baa1e4b0c84637ce36b4", "poolName": "Default", "dashboardID": "582e3a2ff5c650000124c18a", "dashboardName": "Default", "dateCreated": "2017-05-23T13:51:23.558Z", "callbackHeader": {}, "active": true }' "https://example.com:8080/run")`
`reportURL=$(expr "$HerculesResponse" : '.*"reportURL":"\([^"]*\)"')
echo $reportURL
runId=$(echo $reportURL | cut -d"=" -f 2)
echo $runId`

How do I use runId variable outside of this shell script to run the command

`testStatus=$(curl -X GET https://example.com:8080/runs/$runId)`

I tried to use **export runId** command but doesn't work

Comment: `export` makes variables available to *child* processes -- that is, processes you later start. It doesn't make them available to *parent* processes (ie. the process that started you).

Answer (score 1):

When you run your shell script, the variables set by it are lost once its execution finishes and they won't be available to the calling shell.  The right way to extract the value of your variable is to:

- let the script output the value of the variable and use command substitution to assign that value to a variable in the calling shell, like this:

  ```
  run_id=$(/path/to/script.sh)
  ```

The drawback of this approach is that **all output** of the script will end up in the variable.  In your case, the output of `echo $reportURL` as well as `echo $runId`.

- run the script in current shell with `.` or `source` command, like this:

  ```
  . /path/to/script.sh
  ```

  or

  ```
  source /path/to/script.sh
  ```

---

See also:

- [What does "export" do in shell programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411455/what-does-export-do-in-shell-programming)
- [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42290320/6862601)