# Why does Node not read the env var of the current shell?

Tags: node.js, shell, environment-variables

As you can see below, I set an environment variable `FOO`, but when I execute `console.log` on the next line, it's `undefined`. If I set it on the same line where I execute `console.log`, it is present. Why is the behaviour as such?

```
$ FOO="123"
$ echo $FOO
123
$ node -e "console.log(process.env.FOO)"
undefined
$ FOO="123" node -e "console.log(process.env.FOO)"
123
```

Node version: 6.6.0

Comment: you need to use `export FOO= "123"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set the environment variable for the current terminal session, you need to use `EXPORT`

So, this code will work

```
export FOO=123
node -e "console.log(process.env.FOO)"
123
```

`EXPORT` makes the assignment visible to subprocesses. Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411455/what-does-export-do-in-shell-programming) for more details

Comment: Thank you very much! The code works great, but for the benefit of future readers it would be great if you could explain what's the reason why this needs to be done.

Comment: Yes I can, but I think the link provided by the community ([What does “export” do in shell programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411455/what-does-export-do-in-shell-programming) ) does it better than I am able to do it.

Comment: I get that, but I had to scroll all the way down to the bottom on that thread to find the explanation :(

Comment: I added one more line and a link to the other thread