# How to make bashdb and VS Code's Debugger use the same environment and functions from the user .bashrc?

Tags: bash, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.39.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 to debug a bash script.

In my environment `.bashrc` file, I have defined a function `hello1`:

```
function hello1
{
    echo Hello from .bashrc!
}
```

In my bash script, I've added another function `hello2`:

```
function hello2
{
    echo Hello from your script!
}
```

and the script contains the lines:

```
hello1
hello2
```

Now set the following launch configuration:

```
{
    "type": "bashdb",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Debug: Active script",
    "program": "${file}"
}
```

Before debugging, enter the `Terminal` window within VS code. Type `hello1` and the output is `Hello from .bashrc!`. Then type `hello2` and as expected, `Command 'hello2' not found` is the result because this function is not known to the bash shell. All good.

Now debug from within VS Code (choose the `Debug: Active script` configuration with the script active). Watch the `Debug Console` window as you step through the script. This time `hello2` works but you get an error for `hello1`:

```
line X: hello1: command not found
```

How do you make `bashdb` and the `Debug Console` window understand environment and functions from the user `.bashrc`?

Comment: The two `declare -F` lines aren't doing anything useful. Functions are not inherited (by default) from the environment of a parent shell. Don't think of `.bashrc` as a general repository for common code; it's meant to initialize your *interactive* shell, nothing more. If your script needs `hello1`, define it in the script, or have the script source a file that defines it.

Comment: @chepner: That's helpful, thanks. Have removed the `declare -F` calls. They were there just as another way to call the two functions. How to get your user functions and aliases included in your script? Do you mean something like putting all common code in a file called (say) `.bashrc_usr`, then `source ~/.bashrc_usr` in your script? Tried that and it appears to work for functions, but not aliases.

Comment: The aliases are defined, but alias *expansion* is only enabled by default for interactive shells.

Answer (score 1):

It works when you [`export`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7411455/2745495) the function:

```sh
function hello1
{
  echo Hello from bashrc
}
export -f hello1
```

[image]