# Why is "command not found" displaying for tshark commands?

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments, tshark

Whenever I execute a bash script with a tshark command via command prompt, it will not work, displaying "command not found".

I have added a path to the PATH environment variable and tshark works in command prompt itself, however should a tshark command be executed via a bash script that is when the issue arises.

For instance,

`tshark -r <filename here> -e ip.src -e eth.src -e ip.dst -e eth.dst -e ip.ttl -T fields -E separator="," > new.csv`

works as intended when inputted directly into command prompt, however does not work when in a .sh script that is executed via command prompt.

Comment: Have you used the `export` keyword while editing the `PATH` variable? (https://stackoverflow.com/q/7411455/3052438)

Comment: @NO_NAME I have not edited the PATH variable in the script - only in System Properties > Environment variables such that tshark is recognized outside the directory when a command is issued in command prompt. However, even when in the same directory, the script will not work.

Comment: Does the path to `tshark` appear when you're printing the `PATH` from inside the script? Also, make sure the script doesn't have Windows file endings. It can give weird result like this.

Comment: Yes, the PATH variable has all the relevant paths - particularly to tshark - both when displayed in command prompt and when executing from the script. And the file extension is .sh if that is what you mean by file endings.

Comment: Sorry, I've meant line endings.

Comment: Can you provide any other debug from your script?  For example, by adding a `set -x` command to the top.  Run `help set` for other `set` options.  
  
Also, is the path to `tshark` in root's `$PATH`?  If not, does adding it to root's `$PATH` help?  Maybe the script is being run with elevated privileges?